# A projective module over a domain that is not faithfully flat?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, flatness

Let $R$ be a (noncommutative) unital ring **which is a domain** and let  $\mathcal{N}$ be a **non-zero** projective (right) module. Projectivity of course implies that $\mathcal{N}$ is flat, but does the fact that $R$ is also a domain imply that $\mathcal{N}$ is faithfully flat?

Comment: Is that really what you meant to ask? The zero module is projective and torsionfree, but not faithfully flat.

Comment: @Jeremy: I had assumed that $\mathcal{N}$ is non-zero without writing it. I have now edited to make this clear.

Comment: There are still trivial counterexamples. For example, if $R=S\times\mathbb{Z}$ then $0\times\mathbb{Z}$ is projective and torsion-free, but not faithfully flat.

Comment: So I guess I was also assuming that $R$ has no zero-divisors. This rules out the counter example $R = S \times \mathbb{Z}$. Perhaps there are still trivial examples?

Comment: If you ring is a domain, protective implies torsion free. Also, it's kind of unfair to change your questions after getting correct answers.

Comment: @Fernando: Thank you for the information, I have removed the redundent assumption.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I don't think your example is torsion-free: the element $(1,0)\in R$ annihilates the element $(0,1)\in \{0\}\times\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Wojowu For rings that are not domains, I think that “torsion free” usually means that no nonzero element is annihilated by a non zero divisor. Otherwise no nonzero module for a ring that is not a domain  would be torsion free. Appeal to authority: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module

Comment: @Wojowu Of course, you might argue that if one can’t even be bothered to be a domain, then one doesn’t deserve to have any torsion free modules.